# Exist another kind of "Application architecture" available?

Tags: cocoa, architecture

I only found "Document-Based Application Architecture" in Cocoa. Is there another kind of "Application architecture" available?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there’s also the sort where you don’t use `NSDocument`.

A more goal-oriented question might get a more helpful answer.